# If is domain, display this array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Have two arrays. One shuffles images, other one has no shuffle. When you go to the website, it's supposed to display images in a random order. That works. Now, I'd like it if you're being forwarded from this other domain that it displays the other array with no shuffle.

Here's my array with no shuffle:

```
<?

$items1 = array(

    array('image'=>'/images/logos/1.png', 'link' => 'http://www.blah.com', 'text' => 'blah'),
    array('image'=>'/images/logos/2.png', 'link' => 'http://www.blah.com', 'text' => 'blah'),
    array('image'=>'/images/logos/3.png', 'link' => 'http://www.blah.com', 'text' => 'blah'),
    array('image'=>'/images/logos/4.png', 'link' =>     

    );

?>
```

Here's me trying an if else statement to display correct array:

```
<?php $domain = "http://www.blahblah.com";
        if ($domain == blahblah.com)
        { echo '<?foreach($items1 as $i1){?>
          <div>
              <a href="<?=$i1['link'];?>"><img width="400" height="200" src="<?=$i1['image'];?>"></a>
          </div>
       <? } ?>'; }
        else
        { echo '<?foreach($items as $i){?>
          <div>
              <a href="<?=$i['link'];?>"><img width="400" height="200" src="<?=$i['image'];?>"></a>
          </div>
       <? } ?>'; }
       ?>
```

Guide me to the light people! Thanks

**greg0ire**> code suggestion:

```
<?php $domain = "http://www.blahblah.com";
    if ($domain == "http://www.blahblah.com"):// use alternative syntax in templates
      foreach($items1 as $i1): // do not try to "echo 'foreach'" ?>
      <div>
          <a href="<?=$i1['link'];?>"><img width="400" height="200" src="<?=$i1['image'];?>"></a>
      </div>
   <?php 
      endforeach;
    else:
      foreach($items as $i):?>
      <div>
          <a href="<?=$i['link'];?>"><img width="400" height="200" src="<?=$i['image'];?>"></a>
      </div>
   <?php 
       endforeach;
     endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is what you're looking for... ?

[PHP: $_SERVER - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is more what you're looking for.

`HTTP_REFERER` is where the user came from (as set by the useragent)

See: [PHP:$_SERVER - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

You'll also need to check for both `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` (Unless you're set up to use either one or the other)